# How to replace a string at a particular position

Tags: javascript, string, replace, substring

Is there a way to replace a portion of a String at a given position in java script. For instance I want to replace `00` in the hours column with `12` in the below string.The `substring` comes at 13 to 15.

```
Mar 16, 2010 00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following is one option:

```
var myString = "Mar 16, 2010 00:00 AM";

myString = myString.substring(0, 13) + 
           "12" + 
           myString.substring(15, myString.length);
```

Note that if you are going to use this to manipulate dates, it would be recommended to use some date manipulation methods instead, such as those in [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: A slightly faster and more concise approach: for the second part of the string, use `myString.substr(15)` - this will get the string from position `15` till the end of the string.

Answer (score 9):

A regex approach

```
"Mar 16, 2010 00:00 AM".replace(/(.{13}).{2}/,"$112")
Mar 16, 2010 12:00 AM
```

Comment: I like this approach but if anyone is concerned about the performance here's a test comparison: http://jsperf.com/substring-replace

Comment: right, regex are generally slower. That I won't use myself in 2016.

Comment: Ten times slower, but still extremely fast unless you need to perform a million operations per second.

Answer (score 4):

One option would be

```
>>> var test = "Mar 16, 2010 00:00 AM";
>>> test.replace(test.substring(13,15),"12")
```

Comment: Wouldn't that give "Mar 16, 2010 12:12 AM"? You could change it to `test.replace(test.substring(13,16),"12:")` I think (similar to haim's method).

Comment: @Dominic: Good point, but actually it will replace it correctly in this case, because the JavaScript replace() method only replaces the first occurrence. But if the date was "Mar 16 2000", it would not have worked.

Comment: @Daniel - interesting - seems like an odd implementation of String::replace. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 3):

if it is always  `00:` in hours,

you can just replace  `00:` with `12:`

using `replace()` ,

if not u need find the `indexOf` the **`:`** character ,

and then replace 2 digit before with `12`.

Answer (score 0):

You can direclty use [replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method  along with [indexOf()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) of string in Javascript.

Comment: Can you elaborate an example?

Comment: @EuryPérezBeltré I can think about a straight way to do that: `'Mar 16, 2010 00:00 AM'.replace('00:', '12:')`, (even not using `indexOf()`)

Answer (score 0):

Another creative idea could be converting into Array, `splice` and convert it back to String.

```
let str = "Mar 16, 2010 00:00 AM";
let arr = str.split("");
arr.splice(13,2,"1","2");
str = arr.join("");
```