# Replacing words by index position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a some writing tool, that check certain words for markup against my API. the idea is to markup words on the fly while user is still typing on the keyboard or finished to type (draw red underline under matching word).

Now for the start I've used the next function to determine when user stop typing for 1-2 seconds (this is the right moment to grab the text and send it to my API):

```
debounce: function (func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function () {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };

    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  };
}
```

and use it like this:

```
$(this).on('keyup', debounce(function () {              
    check_words($(this).html());
}, 1000));
```

So when I've the current sentense (user can still continue typing) I used  **check_words** function to send AJAX call to my API to check which words should be markup.

The API return JSON respond look like this: 
(for example sentence: "**hello my name is Bob**"):

```
{
  "markup": [{
    "fromPos": 7,
    "toPos": 8,
    "word": "my"
  }, {
    "fromPos": 15,
    "toPos": 16,
    "word": "is"    
  } 
}
```

So it mean 2 words should be markup ("my" and "is") and I also got the word index position on the sentence, the problem is that I can't find solution/method how to replace that word on the element using the word index position?

Any idea which JS function can help me achieve that goal?

Comment: Since you have the begin and end positions of words, did you try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/2236257/1593188

Comment: But how I can perform this solution on the element itself? (because I cannot use the source content because from that time it might changed again - user maybe still typing)

Comment: A naive approach is to compare the content between begin and end positions with "word" from ajax call, if they are similar replace it otherwise make another ajax call based on the current text.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know where exactly the user is typing. I assume it a container with attribute `contenteditable`. Applying styles on these are much simpler than with `<textarea>`.

What you could simply do, is search for the words in the text, and if the position in the text matches the position that we get back from the API, we know that they have not changed.

Now, what you need to be careful about is not removing the cursor focus while the user is typing: this limits the kind of changes that you can do on the text.

I would suggest you put every word the user types into it's own `<span>`s, each with it's id. That way, you can easily apply different classes to it without making any major changes to the DOM. This can be done by listening to the `keyup` events and starting/ending `span`s as required.

You can use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) to get the text without the spans (to search through).

I assume a word can have a different style based on the context; if not you can have the class of each `span` be based on the word inside, so you can style the same word everywhere efficiently.

Comment: Sound like really good solution, but how I can warp each word with a span while the user is still typing? any idea? I can use $(this).html().split(' ').pop(); to get last word but how I wrap it in a span and inject it back while the user still typing?

Comment: You can start here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content; and look into the `execCommands`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand
I am working on a working demo.

Comment: I'm also trying to play with it.. still no solution working