# replace a string partially with something else

Tags: javascript

lets say I have this image address like

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproj-d.appspot.com/o/FILE_NAME.jpg?alt=media&token=124bb2bf-c6ef-432b-92c7-7032563ba31b
```

how is it possible to replace FILE_NAME.jpg with THUMB_FILE_NAME.jpg
Note: FILE_NAME and THUMB_FILE_NAME are not static and fix.

the FILE_NAME is not fixed and I can't use string.replace method.
eventually I don't know the File_Name

Comment: use string.replace method.

Comment: that FILE_NAME is not static

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace a string at a particular position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2236235/how-to-replace-a-string-at-a-particular-position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace`

```
.replace(/(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=(.jpg))/g, "THUMB_FILE_NAME")
```

or if you want to support multiple formats

```
.replace(/(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=(.(jpg|png|jpeg)))/g, "THUMB_FILE_NAME")
```

**Demo**

```js
var output = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproj-d.appspot.com/o/FILE_NAME.jpg?alt=media&token=124bb2bf-c6ef-432b-92c7-7032563ba31b".replace(/(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=(.jpg))/g, "THUMB_FILE_NAME");
console.log( output );
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=\/)` matches `/` but doesn't remember the match
- `[^\/]*` matches till you find next `/`
- `(?=(.jpg)` ensures that match ends with *.jpg*

To match the FILE_NAME, use

```
.match(/(?<=\/)[^\/]*(?=(.(jpg|png|jpeg)))/g)
```

Comment: Which all formats do you support.. you can make it `(?=(.(jpg|png)))`

Comment: thanks. that works. and how to get original FILE_NAME and add THUMB_ prefix and regenerate URL address?

Comment: You can replace `replace` with `match` to get the original `FILE_NAME`

Comment: will you give an example please

Comment: any idea if the is no extension (like .jpg)
so what if the filename doesnt have any extension

Comment: @SaJed It will be difficult, since in that case you will need to specify why *myproj-d.appspot.com* or *firebasestorage.googleapis.com* should not be matched but *FILE_NAME* should.

Answer (score 1):

```
var pattern = /[\w-]+\.(jpg|png|txt)/
var c = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproj-d.appspot.com/o/FILE_NAME.jpg?alt=media&token=124bb2bf-c6ef-432b-92c7-7032563ba31b
'
c.replace(pattern, 'YOUR_FILE_NAME.jpg')
```

you can add any format in the pipe operator

Comment: how to get original File_Name and add thumb_ prefix and regenerate URL again?

Comment: @SaJed to get filename you should do search with the pattern.that provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String's replace method.

```
var a = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproj-d.appspot.com/o/FILE_NAME.jpg?alt=media&token=124bb2bf-c6ef-432b-92c7-7032563ba31b";
a = a.replace('FILE_NAME', 'THUMB_FILE_NAME');
```

Comment: I dont know whats FILE_NAME and either file extension. thats not static.

Comment: If you know the format, you can use split and join to replace the FILE_NAME with THUMB_FILE_NAME.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format, you can use the split and join to replace the FILE_NAME.

```
let str = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/myproj-d.appspot.com/o/FILE_NAME.jpg?alt=media&token=124bb2bf-c6ef-432b-92c7-7032563ba31b";
let str_pieces = str.split('/');
let str_last = str_pieces[str_pieces.length - 1];
let str_last_pieces = str_last.split('?');
str_last_pieces[0] = 'THUMB_' + str_last_pieces[0];
str_last = str_last_pieces.join('?');
str_pieces[str_pieces.length - 1] = str_last;
str = str_pieces.join('/');
```